# How to create a global 401 unauthroized handler using React + ReactQuery + Axios stack?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-query

So I architected frontend in the way which encapsulates every API operation tied to a single resource inside custom hook like this:

```js
export default function useSubjects() {
  const queryClient: QueryClient = useQueryClient();
  const token: string | null = useStore((state) => state.user.token);
  const { yearCourseId } = useParams<{ yearCourseId: string }>();

  const getSubjects = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`yearCourses/${yearCourseId}/subjects`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });
    return response.data;
  };

  const postSubject = async (subject: SubjectType) => {
    const response = await axios.post(`yearCourses/${yearCourseId}/subjects`, subject, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });
    return response.data;
  };

  const query = useQuery(SUBJECTS_QUERY_KEY, getSubjects);

  const postMutation = useMutation(postSubject, {
    onSuccess: (subject: SubjectType) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData(SUBJECTS_QUERY_KEY, (old: any) => [...old, subject]);
    },
  });

  return { query, postMutation };
}
```

Now what is the way to globally handle `401 unauthorized`? I would like to navigate user to `/login` on every unauthorized request. Note that I have more hooks like this tied to other resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `onError` callback. You can also do this globally as a callback on the [queryCache](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryCache#global-callbacks)

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
 queryCache: new QueryCache({
   onError: error => {
     // check for 401 and redirect here
   }
 })
})
```